# any way to study the number of CPU cycles used for a computation?

Tags: performance-tuning, compiler, hardware

I do speed comparisons for various functions and algorithms, and ultimately, the speed of some section of program code depends on the number of CPU cycles. This can vary wildly across operating systems, hardware architectures, compilers, etc. Even for a simple operation, like a division, the number of CPU cycles varies a lot, from 29 to 155, for example, and it also depends on the type (ints vs. doubles vs. floats, etc.).

Is there any way to measure (count?) the number of CPU cycles of a M computation? In the end, even a function call (Sqrt, Tan, ArcCsch, ...) is ultimately an invocation of an algorithm. Can I measure/count that somehow, and perhaps even a whole code section, not just a specific function call. Would the new compiler perhaps provide such tools?

Comment: If you really need cycle count rather than time, you could try using https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CLanguageInterface.html and a C++ builtin cycle counter.